# JBoss: JaxB DataHandler compatibility

Tags: jboss, jaxb, spring-ws

I am using JBoss 5.1 (EAP). I am using Spring webservices (3.0.5).
For marshalling I am using JaxB.

I am using maven.jaxb2.plugin for generating pojo from the schema (xsd).

When I deploy the EAR on the JBoss, I get the following error:

```
    19:05:52,524 ERROR [[eventmanager-ws]] Allocate exception for servlet eventmanager-ws
    com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    javax.activation.DataHandler does not have a no-arg default constructor.
            this problem is related to the following location:
                    at javax.activation.DataHandler
                    at protected javax.activation.DataHandler
                    uk.co.aol.shipmanager.ws.schema.ReportResponse.data
                    at uk.co.aol.shipmanager.ws.schema.ReportResponse
                    at public uk.co.aol.shipmanager.ws.schema.ReportResponse
                    uk.co.aol.shipmanager.ws.schema.ObjectFactory.createReportResponse()
                    at uk.co.aol.shipmanager.ws.schema.ObjectFactory

            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.j>ava:102)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1136)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:202)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:128)
            at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:277)
            at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
            at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
            at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromContextPath(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:>355)
            at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:328)
            at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:317)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingleto>BeanRegistry.java:222)
```

I've checked jaxb2 plugin version and tried using previous version with the assumption that the JBoss got JaxB 2.1.12, tried many version but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your entities you have field with type `DataHandler`. Mark this field with 
`@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient` annotation

```
class SomeEntity  
{  
    //...   
   @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient  
   private javax.activation.DataHandler yourField;  
   // ...  
}
```

Comment: I have the same error. Generated the client from wsdl using wsimport. What ist wring with my jboss 5.1 GA?